# Regular Expression for split multiple strings with different pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split strings into multiple strings using regex.
I have strings like the following:

- '1. 10.25% 2. 11% 3. 9.75% 4. 4.3%'
- '1.promising.2.inappropriately3.essential.4.intense.'
- '1. He has not been attending 2. English classes 3. since one month4. No error'
- '1. X got 15 shares2. B got 25 shares3. W got 54. shares.4. Mark got 2.5 shares'

I am expecting output like this:

- '1. X got 15 shares' '2. B got 25 shares', '3. W got 54. shares.', '4. Mark got 2.5 shares'
- '1. 10.25%'
- '2. 11% '
- '3. 9.75%'
- ' 4. 4.3%'

I want to write a single expression that split all the given scenarios.
I tried writing the following expression but it fails in some cases

```py
re.split(r'(?=[1-9]{1}\.[\s]?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\:\(\)\-\,\% ]+)', string)
```

Comment: Regex can't perform math operations, so task with *"sequential numbers"* will be better to solve using python.

Comment: please write the expected output

Comment: Not that much of a problem untill you threw `"W got 54. shares"` in the mix.

Comment: This is a really horrible bit of text to format with regex!! `3. W got 54. shares.4. Mark got 2.5 shares` 

Comment: @JvdV yes If dot comes in between is creating a problem for me. Also in some cases, I have strings with float numbers.

Comment: Even if you get Python to check sequences, what is to say you won't have data like `"3. W got 4. shares.4. Mark got 4. shares."`?

Comment: I *would* have suggested some (non-regex) python code to look for sequential numbers to split the string, but that last example appears undecidable programatically. How can the code know whether the "correct" answer is to split it as `["3. W got 5", "4. shares.4. Mark got 2.5 shares"`] or `["3. W got 54. shares.", "4. Mark got 2.5 shares"]`??

Comment: In an ideal world I'd push back on getting cleaner input in the first place, because this data you're working with is horribly messy. But failing that, you need to find a logical rule that works in all of your scenarios -- it's unclear to me what this might be, because it seems you have some gnarly edge cases to deal with like `15`, `2.5` and `54.` *inside* the sections to split!

Comment: @TomLord it's not feasible for me to get clear input data so I am looking for alternative logic which works in all possible scenarios.

Comment: @RahulKadam "All possible" is a very difficult thing to define when the data is this messy... At best, you might need to accept that your solution works for *most* scenarios, because there's always going to be some obscure edge case that can trip you up. For example, as shown in other comments I made here, I can construct sample input where the "correct" interpretation is *ambiguous*.

Comment: It's not solvable task, you will get false splits and no matter how many cases you will predict in your solution. To solve this you need to analyze text with human brain [*(or lame artificial parody)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network). You differ index from other number from context which can't be implemented in algorithm.

Comment: @TomLord will be going to look at input data that split perfectly on a single logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking for each subsequent number used in a `(?<!\d)NUM\.` (the *NUM* with a `.` right after and no other preceding digit) pattern and split at those positions only:

```py
import re

texts = ['1. 10.25% 2. 11% 3. 9.75% 4. 4.3%',
'1.promising.2.inappropriately3.essential.4.itense.',
'1. He has not been attending 2. English classes 3. since one month4. No error',
'1. X got 15 shares2. B got 25 shares3. W got 54. shares.4. Mark got 2.5 shares']

pattern = r'(?<!\d){}\.'
for text in texts:
    bps = []
    prev = 0
    for i in range(1,1000):
        rx = re.compile(pattern.format(i))
        m = rx.search(text, prev)
        if m:
            if prev != m.start():
                bps.append(text[prev:m.start()].strip())
            prev = m.start()
        else:
            break
    if prev < len(text) - 1:
        bps.append(text[prev:].strip())
    print(bps)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8tqFll).

Output:

```
['1. 10.25%', '2. 11%', '3. 9.75%', '4. 4.3%']
['1.promising.', '2.inappropriately', '3.essential.', '4.itense.']
['1. He has not been attending', '2. English classes', '3. since one month', '4. No error']
['1. X got 15 shares', '2. B got 25 shares', '3. W got 54. shares.', '4. Mark got 2.5 shares']
```

Note the `rx = re.compile(pattern.format(i))` and `m = rx.search(text, prev)` lines: the pattern is compiled since the `Pattern.search` method allows searching from the specified position, which is the previous match start position.

The `range(1,1000)` part can be adjusted, `1000` assumes you have up to 999 bullet points in the text.

Comment: It's an hard nut to crack. Imagine what happens if W. only had 4 shares?

Comment: My concern is that with such messy input, such a solution might not work!... For instance, what if it's: `1. W got 2. shares.2. X got 1 share.3.Y for 4.4. Z got 5.5.`? At a certain point you just might need to accept that the data is too damn messy, and push back on getting a cleaner "split" earlier in the funnel!

Comment: @TomLord In this case, it is a matter of [precising the regex](https://ideone.com/WtghaS).

Comment: @JvdV Then the `2.` in `2. shares` is a valid split point.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In the example I gave above, is the "correct" answer to split on `["1. W got", "2. shares.2. X got 1 share"]` or `["1. W got 2. shares.", "2. X got 1 share"]`? It's ambiguous.

Comment: @TomLord Yeah, but there are no other ways to disambiguate here. Unless OP has more specifications to consider, this is the best OP could get.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works perfectly on the cases specified in the question.  I think I need to give a clear input regex.